# 1980s or late 70s comic featuring a space ark with humanity frozen on board and a romance?

Tags: story-identification, comics, post-apocalyptic

I may be remembering this incorrectly, but was a large hardbound SF anthology with several comics.  May have been black and white, don't remember color.

In one particular story, there is a space ark carrying several shining examples of humanity, who are frozen in suspended animation for the long journey.  Most of them are beautiful females, but there are a few males too to help rebuild the population.

A female is unfrozen too soon, and wakes up to find an older male who has also been unfrozen.  They are alone on this spacecraft and cannot return to suspended animation because, conveniently, to go through the process again would kill them.

So, since they're bored and going to die anyway, they start a romance that goes through all the typical phases including jealousy, betrayal, etc.  The male passenger turns on the female and attempts to kill her by re-freezing her in the cryogenic process.  Turns out her unfroze himself early on purpose and has been thawing out, then killing new girlfriends for years.  At the expense of humanity!  I believe the woman won the battle and then began unfreezing the men?

I was like 11 or 12 when I read this (so 1981 or 1982).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I believe this was [Weird Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weird_Science_%28comics%29), a comic written in the early 1950's. The 22 issues were published in four hardbound volumes in 1980 as part of 'The Complete EC Library'. I remember the story you describe occurring within it, called '[50 Girls 50' by Al Williamson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Williamson) - this link includes a color picture of one of pages of the story mentioned (the compendium was published in black and white).